# кэш не очищается по окончанию срока жизни Laravel

Tags: laravel, кэширование

всем привет, разбираю систему кэширования Laravel 8. Столкнулся с проблемой, что кэш не очищается по истечению времени жизни. Такое чувство что навсегда запоминается. Перелопатил всю документацию, не нашел ничего путного по этому поводу. Драйвер кэширования стандартный на файлах

```
if (Cache::has('key')) {
            $data = Cache::get('key');
            return $data;
        } else {
             --- код ---
            
            Cache::put('key', $results, $seconds);
            return $results;
        }
```

Comment: А вы уверены что у вас только одно место пишет на этот ключ?

Comment: А почему ты сделал вывод, что кеш записывается навсегда? дампа или прото проверяешь наличие файлов?

Comment: Приложите больше кода. В том числе config/cache.php

Answer (score 0):

В общем оказалось намного проще - не был настроен сборщик мусора. Всем спасибо за участие ))